# how can we solve this equation without mellin transform?

Tags: inverse-problems

given the equation (functional equation)

$$ f(x)+f(2x)+f(3x)+.... =g(x) $$

we can use the Mobius tranform to obtain

$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g(nx)\mu(n) $$

however, what can we do with the equation

$$ f(x)-f(2x)+f(3x)-f(4x)+... =g(x) $$ ?

how can we invert this equation to get the solution $ f(x)$ ??

Comment: In the title, you mention Mellin transform, which has little to do with Möbius transform, is this a typo ?

Comment: @user8268 : no it is $\nu(n) = \sum_{2^k | n} 2^k \mu(n/2^k)$, this is because $1 / \sum_n n^{-s} (-1)^{n+1}  = \sum_k 2^k 2^{-sk} / \sum_n n^{-s}$

Comment: @user1952009 oops, I made a mistake (deleted my comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that $g$ is given and you are looking for $f$.
We can remark that
$$\begin{split}g(x)+2g(2x)&
 =f(x)-f(2x)+f(3x)-f(4x)+\cdots+2f(2x)-2f(4x)+\cdots\\
 &=f(x)+f(2x)+f(3x)-3f(4x)+\cdots\end{split}$$
and this gives the hint to consider
$$g(x)+2g(2x)+4g(4x)+\cdots=f(x)+f(2x)+f(3x)+\cdots$$
and you're back to the previous problem.

Comment: you mean $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2ng(2n)=f(x)+f(2x)+f(3x)+f(4x)+.....$

Comment: @JoseGarcia. No, I mean $\sum_n2^ng(2^nx)$, really.